# Applying commits from template repository to derived by copying repos with git

Tags: node.js, git

I have a **Node.js** based `starter` repo with initialisation code for other custom micro-services. `starter` repo is updated constantly to meet changes in APIs it's communicating with. Some of them are breaking, so changes need to be propagated on growing number of custom micro-services.

My current flow is:

1. pull latest `master` from `starter` repo
2. copy files to new folder e.g. `custom-repo-13`
3. make custom changes to `custom-repo-13`

This works good until, e.g. in 6 months, `starter` repo will have 30 new commits and 1 breaking change that needs to be propagated to other repos.

My current flow for this situation:

For each custom repo:

1. identify `new commits`
2. apply them one by one by manually copy-pasting
3. validate everything by running set of unit tests

*Question:* Is there some way of automatically, leveraging the power of GIT, to apply these `new commits` to custom, standalone repositories?

Comment: Without specifying any other technologies you're using, it's difficult to suggest the best solution. For instance, you may be best using a package manager if a suitable one exists.

Comment: updated question.

Comment: After updating your question, it _really_ sounds like your `starter` repo should provide an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/), which can be properly versioned. This does not make use of git, but this is exactly the point of a package manager.

Comment: This doesn't sound clear to me, but you will loose the power of git if you begin to copy paste to other repositories. I don't really understand why custom-repo aren't based on starter branches.